# Android Fragment Re-Instantiation Error

Tags: android

I thought I had my conversion to fragments pretty well done until I rotated the screen. I am getting the following types of errors:

RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ghcssoftware.gedstar/com.ghcssoftware.gedstar.GedStar}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.ghcssoftware.gedstar.PersonTab$PersonTabFrag: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

The class in question does exist, is public, and I added an empty constructor with no change in the results. Looking at some sample code, I do notice some differences from the way my code is written, although I don't see empty constructors either:

1) Is there any reason that my fragment class should be declared "static" as many samples are?

2) Do I need to implement the use of "newInstance" within my fragment class? Why is this done instead of just having a constructor? For example from one of the V14 samples:

```
public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {
        CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
```

I'm still a bit unfamiliar with some Java concepts, so may be missing something basic here.

Doug Gordon
  GHCS Software

Comment: I'm not sure about what's happening with your rotation issue, but this page describes the purpose of the static class declaration: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any reason that my fragment class should be declared "static" as many samples are?

Only if it is an inner class of something. Since yours appears to be an inner class of `PersonTab`, then it will need to be static. Or, move it outside of `PersonTab` to be a standalone Java class.

> Do I need to implement the use of "newInstance" within my fragment class? Why is this done instead of just having a constructor?

It is just a factory method. It is not required by the framework.

Comment: Looking for a little clarification: when I rotate the screen with the app running, my activity is "restarted" -- correct? So who is it that is trying to instantiate my fragment class? When first started, my activity itself creates the object and adds it to its container view. Wouldn't it simply do this again after the rotation? And then why would it fail -- what's the difference?

Comment: @gordonwd: "So who is it that is trying to instantiate my fragment class?" -- I can't answer that, as you have not indicated whether this is set up via `<fragment>` or a `FragmentTransaction`. "Wouldn't it simply do this again after the rotation?" -- yes. "And then why would it fail -- what's the difference?" -- there is no difference. Please understand that we are not mind readers. We can only go by the evidence that you supply. Your evidence indicates you have a flaw in your fragment class declaration, as I noted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, Mark -- I realize that. Even though I guess I know how to fix this, i'd like to understand what's going on a bit better, so I think I'll put in some breakpoints so I can see at what point things are going awry (before doing the "fix"). My fragments are all added by transactions, BTW. I have a fairly complex existing app and was trying to take some shortcuts to making it fragment-friendly, but you know how that goes...

Comment: @gordonwd: To clarify a previous point, if your fragment is dynamic, and you have `setRetainInstance(true)`, then the fragment should not be recreated at all, but rather carried between activity instances. But I'm now similarly confused -- if everything is dynamic, I would not have expected to see that stack trace. AFAIK, you're the only one creating the fragments, and that error should only occur if the system were trying to create one (e.g., via `<fragment>`). If you think of it, comment back with your resolution, as I'd be curious to know where things are going wrong.

Comment: My fragment is dynamic, is not in the back stack (it's part of my "main" app), and I did not setRetainInstance(true). But Android is trying to create a new instance of it since the above error is occurring when my activity's onCreate calls super.onCreate after a config change.

Comment: I don't think that I really want to use setRetainInstance since my fragment's view as well as its parent view are substantially different in portrait vs. landscape, so it's easier just to start over from scratch. However, my current fragment classes are structured poorly since I was trying to quickly port over from my pre-Honeycomb design and I'll just have to take a step back, do it right this time, and at least this re-instantiation error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

2).
Passing a variable throw newInstance function argument, in your case it's num, allows to exclude class private variable that needed to bring value between constractor and onCreateView. For int variable it sove nothing, but for long string... 
regards, 
yury