# Why DialogFragment can't be an inner class?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

If I had my `DialogFragment` declared as an **inner** class I got an `InstantiationException` on `orientation change`, i.e. when instance is recreated, which says there is no public constructor, class isn't public etc. In fact everything is `public`, default constructor is in place. If I just move this `DialogFragment` to a separate file - everything goes fine. I'm not looking for a workaround, I just want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think `DialogFragment`s, if within a class, have to be `static`. Unfortunately, I don't have any citation for this, just that every working example I've seen uses the `static` implementation. From the gist of your post yesterday, I get that this isn't a feasible solution, but I believe this is the case. Perhaps someone else can shed more light on this...

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I just want to understand what is going on behind the scenes, why this happens.

Comment: Yes i have exactly same problem with ViewPager and Fragment class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a restriction in Java based on how `Fragments` are created and recreated.

It seems that all `Fragment`s have to be reinstantiated in certain situations<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275571/android-fragment-re-instantiation-error)</sup>, such as orientation changes (and I would guess upon initialization, depending on how the `Fragment` is created). This means that it will be reinstantiated from outside your outer class. However, a non-`static` inner class cannot be instantiated from outside the outer class.<sup>[[2]](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html)</sup> There are also other cases in which a `Fragment` would need to be communicated with from outside the class.<sup>[[3]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/Y4gKHH-KAOs/-AmrPhydUm4J)</sup>